# Android Static Button Listeners

Tags: java, android, static

Basically I am trying to setup some button listeners for my fragment_home_screen activity. The only problem I keep running in to is while getting the proper view for instantiating the buttons. You see, the view is in a static class, so when I try to setup button listeners, any inner calls must be to static objects.

My app so far has a sliding drawer and a starting fragment.

I would like to call a non-static method from within the listener. Is there any way around this, or a possible solution?

[Scroll Down about mid way to the onCreateView method to see the problem]

```
 public class HomeScreen extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private  BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private  BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private  UUID MY_UUID;
private  final String NAME = "Acceptor";


private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    startUpBluetooth();

}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_screen, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, container, false);

        try {
            Button acceptButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.acceptButton);
            Button connectedButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.connectedButton);
            Button connectButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.connectButton);

            acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // ***problem is here***
                    AcceptThread a = new AcceptThread();
                    a.run();
                }
            });
            connectedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ConnectedThread cc = new ConnectedThread();
                    cc.run();
                }
            });
            connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ConnectThread con = new ConnectThread();
                    con.run();
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e1 ){
            errorToast("We have a button problem: "+e1.toString());
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((HomeScreen) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}



public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    public ConnectThread() {
        ...
    }

    public void run() {
        ...
    }


    public void cancel() {
        ...
    }
}


public  class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread() {
        ...
    }

    public void run() {
       ...
    }


    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
       ...
    }


    public void cancel() {
        ...
    }
}

//this class is in the same file
public class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        ...
    }

    public void run() {
        ...
    }

    public void cancel() {
        ....
    }
}

}
```

Here is the XML:

```
 Fragment_home_screen.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeScreen$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/largeText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connected Thread"
    android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/connectButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect Thread"
    android:id="@+id/connectedButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/largeText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Accept Thread"
    android:id="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/acceptButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/largeText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/connectButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/largeText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/largeText" />
```

```
 Activity_home_screen.xml

 <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeScreen">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.gregorybolet.scoutingapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want the Threads to be static, because then all the global variables they are using would have to be static, then eventually forcing the entire java file to be static. Do you know of a possible work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to call a non-static method from within the listener. Is
>   there any way around this, or a possible solution?

To access `AcceptThread` and `ConnectedThread` classes :

**Option 1.** Make both classes `static` because we can access only static methods and classes in static scope

**Option 2.** Remove `static` from `PlaceholderFragment` class

Also change `newInstance` method:

```
public   PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

       return fragment;
    }
```

and get object of PlaceholderFragment class using new when adding in FragmentManager :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,new PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(
                                                             position + 1))
            .commit();
```

Second option is easy before instead of making all classes static just remove `static` from `PlaceholderFragment` class

Comment: When I remove static from PlacehodlerFragment I get a slew of errors not allowing the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` to run properly. Specifically on the `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)` part.

Comment: @Greg: see my answer again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a static class is the best way to go.

A few suggestions to make it easier:

1. Make the PlaceholderFragment not static;
2. Instantiate the fragment using the regular constructor: `PlaceholderFragment()`;
3. Use the `setArguments(Bundle extras)` method to pass the position.

Basically, do whatever the `newInstance` code is doing happen outside.

**Or...**

Create a new constructor for your fragment:

```
public PlaceholderFragment(int sectionNumber) {
    this();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    setArguments(args);
}
```

By no means `@Override` the default constructor. It's used by Android to recreate the fragment when needed.

Creating this new constructor would allow you to do this:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
        new PlaceholderFragment(position + 1)).commit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a comment thinking it worked (as IntelliJ showed no errors until I cleaned the project). I seem to be having a problem in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` method. Specifically on the `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)` part. The error is: `Non-static method 'newInstance(Int)' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. No problem. But look at my answer. By creating a new constructor, you won't use the static method `newInstance(int)`. Instead, you use the perfectly non-static constructor. But anyway, glad you had your problem solved. :)